# Selenium - Changing the pageload

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I encounter the following exception when navigating to an url with `wd.Url = url`:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL ... timed out after 60 seconds."
```

As I already know this exception, I entered the following:

```
wd = new ChromeDriver(cds, co);

wd.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240);
wd.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

But it doesn't change anything. The exception remains the same.
I think this is weird, because it should at least change the timespan of the timeout.

Comment: This issue might not have anything to do with the settings you have enabled, because those settings are for `WebDriver` specifically, and can't help much in the event of language bindings failure. I recommend reading the comments from Selenium developers on this GitHub issue, because I have been down this path before: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5457

Comment: the exception you are getting refers to a timeout for connecting to the remote WebDriver.  The PageLoad timeout you are setting refers to the amount of time the WebDriver waits for the browser (in this case remote browser) to load a page.  These are two different timeouts.

Comment: it's possible this is not remote?  It may show this error even when run locally...  show your initialization code.  Also try using the standard .get(URL) method instead.